# C# lock object inside instance object

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, external, critical-section

i faced ith situation that force me to lock a lock object that is inside of instance object i want to know is it true or not?

for clarify :

```
public class classA
{
    object objLock = new object();
    public void MethodA(object objClassA)
    {
        classA cls = (classA)objClassA;
        lock(cls.objLock)
        {
            Do something with cls
        }
     }
}
```

is it allowed to do it?

Comment: What you're doing is syntactically legal, but the code looks suspect.

Answer (score 5):

The object you lock on is in the same class, but a different instance. In that sense you are not breaking encapsulation, but you should still prefer extracting that code so you can prevent locking on an external object. Here's an example:

```
public class classA
{
    private readonly object objLock = new object();

    public void MethodA(object objClassA)
    {
        classA cls = (classA)objClassA;

        cls.DoSomething();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        lock (this.objLock)
        {
            Do something with cls
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine. It is legal C#.  In fact this is the preferred way instead of locking **this**. Because **this** can be locked from outside the class whereas **objLock** being private can only be locked within the class, giving you better control and avoiding some deadlock conditions

However the casting could potentially throw an exception. You might want to handle that scenario

Comment: Is it not the case though that because he is locking on an object in a different instance that he could still run into deadlock issues (i.e locking on a private variable in another instance is really no different from locking on "this")?  As the other answer mentioned really no external code should be locking on objects within the class (or the class itself), even if those external objects are instances of the same class.

Comment: my big concern is about the deadlock.but i found that using thread synchronization can solve this problem.The "do something with cls" in my question is inside while loop.